# CSS Card Flips won't go next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have 3 cards that flip on hover, but they won't go next to each other and instead go top-to-bottom. They are supposed to all be next to each other, filling up the entire page lengthwise, but are instead making the page extremely long and having to scroll down to access all the information.

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}


/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 350px;
  height: 480px;
}


/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <!-- front content -->
      <p class="title3">Certifications<sub>+</sub></p>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <!-- back content -->
      <p class="title3">Certifications</p>
      <p class="text">
        <ul>
          <li>SDA Certified</li>
          <li>ETA Customer Service Specialist</li>
          <li>ICT Spreadsheet Essentials</li>
          <li>ICT CyberSecurity Essentials</li>
          <li>FERPA 101 for Local Education Agencies</li>
          <li>FERPA 201: Data Sharing</li>
          <li>FERPA for Colleges and Universities</li>
          <li>GCN Seclusion and Restraint - MI</li>
          <li>Nominee of National Academy of Future Scientists and Technologists</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The cards end up all being left-aligned in a tower, and I need them to be aligned all in a row across the page.

Comment: `div`s are block elements. They will naturally stack. You need to use some other display method if you wish for them to occupy the same row.  `display: inline || inline-block || flex || table`

Comment: You state your problem is with 3 flipping cards but you code only has 1 card, where is the rest of the markup?

Comment: the 3 cards have the exact same code as the first one for now so i didn't include them to not use up too much space

Comment: @mrjodicow got ya... and they are just placed one after another inside the `flip-container` correct?

Comment: @zgood they are each in a separate `flip-container` and are also formatted as flex with `order: 1;` `order: 2;` etc.

Comment: @mrjodicow elaborate your question more.

Comment: @MerajKhan there are 3 boxes. they stack, but need to go next to each other. can't elaborate much more than that

Comment: @mrjodicow To the parent div give `display:flex`